# Function executes when an alert is placed before the calling

Tags: javascript, json

First of all I'm sorry for the really vague title, but I have no clue how to name the title. So if someone has a better name, please let me know and I'll edit it.

I have made some sort of a calculator, where the cost of ownership gets calculated. The input of values comes from the user or a preset from a database. The presets can be chosen with a select, and I use the `onchange-event` to change input data.

```
<select id="myID" onchange="getPreset(this.value)">
  <option>Some options...</option>
</select>
```

In the `getPreset()` function I do some stuff + I call another function which I use to get the data from a database via JSON.

```
function getInfo(name){
  var xmlhttp;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      var info = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

      //process data
      calculate();
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "myphppage.php?name="+name, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This is how my code is now and it works fine and as it should. But before I had placed `calculate();` after `xmlhttp.send();`, which didn't work as it should have. The data got calculated only AFTER I chose another option. For example: first time I chose option 1 - nothing happens. Second time I chose option 2 - data gets calculated like option 1 is chosen.

I get that it was just the wrong place to put the function, but here's what I found strange: if I put an alert before the calling of the function, the data did get calculated. So my code was as following (so you can see it visually):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      var info = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

      //process data
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "myphppage.php?name="+name, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  alert("make it work.");
  calculate();
}
```

As I have no idea why this is and I'm curious to know, I'm asking it here. I hope someone can help me explain.

Comment: Firstly, you can't execute an `onchange` event if the same option has been selected (i.e. *Re-selecting* the first option)

Comment: I tried `onblur` as well, gave the same result. It was all about the placing of the `calculate` function. What I found strange is that placing an alert before calling the function on the wrong place did make it work.

Comment: In your second example, the `calcuate()` function called is immediately after the AJAX Call, which ***isn't*** synchronous, Thus it hasn't any data to calculate with. As `calcuate()` was executed before the AJAX Call was able to finish. Maybe the second time round, it's able to use the Variables collected from the first AJAX Call, therefore calculates them.

Comment: Also, an alert would essentially delay the script; giving more time for the values to be returned. As alerts after all are a control flow statement & stops the execution flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of everything is asynchronous. While the alert pops up you (eventually) get the data and it's calculated correctly. That's why it works. If the connection is veeeery slow or you click 'ok' on the alert button extremely fast, it might fail. That's why you should put it in the correct place :)

Comment: I completely forgot that AJAX is asynchronous, due to my inexperience with it. Learned another lesson today!

Comment: @RobbeVanWinckel It's somehow funny, that you forgot `"Asynchronous JavaScript and XML`" being asynchronous  ; ).

Comment: @Teemu Haha, I know :D I facepalmed myself when I looked at what AJAX stands for. But hey, stupid mistakes are the most common things ;)